# DataTable selector has black box around it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

Not sure where I've gone wrong, here's the issue:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
<?php

require 'config.php';

?>
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.ico">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

    <title>Vendor list - VendorBase Pro</title>

    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS     -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables/datatables.min.css"/>   







    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS     -->



    <!-- Animation library for notifications   -->
    <link href="assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--  Light Bootstrap Table core CSS    -->

    <link href="assets/css/light-bootstrap-dashboard.css?v=1.4.0" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="DataTables/DataTables-1.10.20/css/jQuery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!--  CSS for Demo Purpose, don't include it in your project     -->

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"/>
    <link href="assets/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<style>

td.details-control {
    background: url('https://www.datatables.net/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.details td.details-control {
    background: url('https://www.datatables.net/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}


  td {
      overflow:hidden;
      table-layout: fixed;
      max-width: 500px;
    overflow-wrap:break-word;
      }


</style>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar" data-color="blue" data-image="assets/img/sidebar-5.jpg">

    <!--   you can change the color of the sidebar using: data-color="blue | azure | green | orange | red | purple" -->


        <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="http://www.creative-tim.com" class="simple-text">
                    VendorBase Pro
                </a>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="dashboard.php">
                        <i class="pe-7s-graph"></i>
                        <p>Dashboard</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="user.php">
                        <i class="pe-7s-user"></i>
                        <p>User Profile</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="table.php">
                        <i class="pe-7s-note2"></i>
                        <p>Vendor List</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="typography.html">
                        <i class="pe-7s-news-paper"></i>
                        <p>Reports</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="icons.html">
                        <i class="pe-7s-science"></i>
                        <p>Settings</p>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="active-pro">
                    <a href="upgrade.html">
                        <i class="pe-7s-rocket"></i>
                        <p>Upgrade to PRO</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-panel">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-example-2">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Vendor List</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                                <p class="hidden-lg hidden-md">Dashboard</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                                    <b class="caret hidden-sm hidden-xs"></b>
                                    <span class="notification hidden-sm hidden-xs">5</span>
                                    <p class="hidden-lg hidden-md">
                                        5 Notifications
                                        <b class="caret"></b>
                                    </p>
                              </a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Notification 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Notification 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Notification 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Notification 4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another notification</a></li>
                              </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                <p class="hidden-lg hidden-md">Search</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                           <a href="">
                               <p>Account</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <p>
                                        Dropdown
                                        <b class="caret"></b>
                                    </p>

                              </a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                              </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <p>Log out</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="separator hidden-lg hidden-md"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="header">
                                <h4 class="title">Vendor Database</h4><br>

                                    <table id='tblVendor' class='display cell-border compact stripe' style="width:100%">

                                  <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                      <th>View</th>
                                      <th>Vendor</th>
                                      <th>Company</th>
                                      <th>Type</th>
                                      <th>Status</th>
                                      <th>Owner</th>
                                      <th>Business Email</th>
                                      <th>Department</th>
                                      <th>Descr</th>
                                    </tr>
                                  </thead>

                                </table>                                   

                            </div>                        

                          </div>
                        </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <nav class="pull-left">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Home
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Company
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Portfolio
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                               Blog
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <p class="copyright pull-right">
                    &copy; <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script> <a href="">DeedsTech, Inc.</a>, Third Party Risk Management Solutions.
                </p>
            </div>
        </footer>


    </div>

<!-- Central Modal Medium Info -->
<div class="modal fade" id="activev" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-notify modal-info" role="document">
    <!--Content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!--Header-->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <p class="heading lead">Modal Info</p>

        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true" class="white-text">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <!--Body-->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="text-center">
          <i class="fas fa-check fa-4x mb-3 animated rotateIn"></i>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit iusto nulla aperiam blanditiis
            ad consequatur in dolores culpa, dignissimos, eius non possimus fugiat. Esse ratione fuga, enim,
            ab officiis totam.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--Footer-->
      <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Get it now <i class="far fa-gem ml-1 text-white"></i></a>
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">No, thanks</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.Content-->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Central Modal Medium Info-->

<!-- make rows in tables clickable -->
<!--
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

    const rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr[data-href]");

    rows.forEach(row => {
        row.addEventListener("click", () => {
            window.location.href = row.dataset.href;
        });
    });
    });

</script>
-->
</body>



  <!--   Core JS Files   -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->

<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.12.0/js/mdb.min.js"></script>

    <!--  Notifications Plugin    -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>

    <!-- Light Bootstrap Table Core javascript and methods for Demo purpose -->
    <script src="assets/js/light-bootstrap-dashboard.js?v=1.4.0"></script>

    <!-- Light Bootstrap Table DEMO methods, don't include it in your project! -->
    <script src="assets/js/demo.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>




</html>
<script>
function format ( d ) {

    return '<table>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td><b>Business Owner:</b></td>'+
            '<td>'+d.owner+'</b></td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td><b>Contact Email:</b></td>'+
            '<td>'+d.owner_email+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td><b>Description:</d></td>'+
            '<td style="max-width=280px;">'+d.descr+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>More Info:</td>'+
            '<td><button>View</button></td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';

}


$(document).ready(function() {
    var dt = $('#tblVendor').DataTable( {
        "responsive": true,
        "dom": 'Bfrtip',

        "buttons":[
         { extend: 'copy', text: 'Copy to Clipboard', className: 'btn btn-info btn-fill' },
         { extend: 'pdf', text: 'Export PDF', className: 'btn btn-info btn-fill' },
         { extend: 'excel', text: 'Export Excel', className: 'btn btn-info btn-fill' },
         { extend: 'csv', text: 'Export CSV', className: 'btn btn-info btn-fill' }


    ],

        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "ajax.php",
        'serverMethod': 'post',
        "columns": [
            {
                "width": "5%",
                "class":          "details-control",
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ""

            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "company" },
            { "data": "type" },
            { "data": "status" },
            { "data": "owner", "visible": false},
            { "data": "owner_email", "visible": false},
            { "data": "descr", "visible": false},
            { "data": "dept" },


        ],  "order": [[1, 'asc']],


    } );

        new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons( dt, {
        buttons: [
            {
                className: 'btn btn-info btn-fill',
                text: 'Add New Vendor',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, conf ) {
                    window.location.replace("new.php");
                },


            },

        ]

    } );

    // Array to track the ids of the details displayed rows
    var detailRows = [];

    $('#tblVendor tbody').on( 'click', 'tr td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = dt.row( tr );
        var idx = $.inArray( tr.attr('id'), detailRows );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            tr.removeClass( 'details' );
            row.child.hide();

            // Remove from the 'open' array
            detailRows.splice( idx, 1 );
        }
        else {
            tr.addClass( 'details' );
            row.child( format( row.data() ) ).show();

            // Add to the 'open' array
            if ( idx === -1 ) {
                detailRows.push( tr.attr('id') );
            }
        }
    } );

    // On each draw, loop over the `detailRows` array and show any child rows
    dt.on( 'draw', function () {
        $.each( detailRows, function ( i, id ) {
            $('#tblVendor'+id+' td.details-control').trigger( 'click' );
        } );
    } );

    dt.buttons( 1, null ).container().appendTo(
        dt.table().container()
    );

} );
</script>
```

I have literally tried everything, even searching through CSS (no changes permanently made) and making changes to color schemes and what not. There literally is nothing that has worked so I'm reaching out to you guru's to see where I'm going wrong. I'm hoping it's just a silly oversight and no drastic changes but I'm open to anything.

Comment: Try to use select element tool to inspect that black part and see which css code is effecting it.

Comment: can you share url?

Comment: @codedUnknown, try to post code that other users can copy - past to some fiddle and reproduce the issue. Try to provide a minimal reproducible code

Comment: Just take a look in the inspector and see which classes are being used and overwrite them in your file, should not be too hard